# Get classname of the running Databricks Job

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks, aws-databricks

There is an **Apache Spark Scala** project (*runnerProject*) that uses another one in the same package (*sourceProject*). The aim of the source project is to get the name and version of the Databricks job that is running.

The problem with the following method is that when **it is called from the *runnerProject*, it returns the *sourceProject's* details, not the *runnerProject*'s name and version**.

sourceProject's method:

```
class EnvironmentInfo(appName: String) {
 
override def getJobDetails(): (String, String) = {
    val classPackage = getClass.getPackage

    val jobName = classPackage.getImplementationTitle
    val jobVersion = classPackage.getImplementationVersion

    (jobName, jobVersion)
  }
 }
```

runnerProject uses sourceProject as a package:

```
import com.sourceProject.environment.{EnvironmentInfo}

 class runnerProject {
  def start(
      environment: EnvironmentInfo
  ): Unit = {

// using the returned parameters of the environment

}
```

How can this issue be worked around in a way that the *getJobDetails()* runs in the *sourceProject*, so that it can be called from other projects as well, not just the *runnerProject*. And also, it should **return the details about the "caller" job**.

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, it gets the calling class name from the stack trace, and uses that to get the actual class, and it's package.

```
class EnvironmentInfo(appName: String) {
 
override def getJobDetails(): (String, String) = {
    val callingClassName = Thread.currentThread.getStackTrace()(2).getClassName
    val classPackage = Class.forName(callingClassName).getPackage

    val jobName = classPackage.getImplementationTitle
    val jobVersion = classPackage.getImplementationVersion

    (jobName, jobVersion)
  }
 }
```

It will work if you call it directly, it might give you the wrong package if you call it from within a lambda function.